# Testing MonoTouch App in iOS Simulator with iOS 4.3.2

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

**UPDATE:** Now that I'm proud owner of MonoTouch and can build against the device this problem bit me again. I can still target 4.3 for Simulator Builds but not for the device where it only allows me to select the 5.0 SDK. Just like it was before I had installed the XCode 3.2.5 which came with the 4.3 SDK. Any suggestions?

- App is configured for a 4.3 Deployment target
- I've installed the "iOS 4.3 Simulator" from within XCode 4
- In the iOS Simulator Hardware Menu I am able to select Version "4.3.2 (8H7)" or "5.0 (9A334)"
- When I choose Version 4.3.2 in the emulator it switches to 4.3.2 as expected
- When I now run my app against the emulator it immediately goes back to 5.0

I am unable to test the app against iOS Version 4.3.2 in the emulator. Am I missing something?

Comment: In the project properties change the target sdk to 4.3.

Comment: Hmm I can only select 5.0 or default. Looks like a need an older SDK. Is that supported?

Comment: I upgraded to 5.0 from 4.3, and 4.3 is there. I am pretty sure you need to have the older sdk installed as well. You may have to re-install the 5.0 sdk after installing 4.3.

Comment: The solution was to download the XCode 3.2.5 installer from the iOS Developer Portal. After that the 4.3 SDK shows up in the build settings.

Comment: Glad it worked. In older versions of monodevelop 2.4, the options would show up, but you still had to install the relevant sdk.

Comment: @Ingenu: I've updated the question. Any idea where to look?

Comment: If you want to deploy to a 4.3 device then go to the project properties and set the iPhone build to target 4.3. Then your app will work on 4.3. Now, the sdk used to build the final project is 5.0, which can target 4.3

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I am facing the same problem, installed the 4.3 simulator but it switches back to 5.0 even if I have set the deployment target to 4.3.